# Accessing TelephonyManager method iccExchangeSimIO

Tags: android, telephonymanager

I am trying to access [iccExchangeSimIO](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#iccExchangeSimIO(int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20java.lang.String)) from TelephonyManager as follows:

```
TelephonyManager mTelephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
byte[] uiccFileReadResponse = mTelephonyManager.iccExchangeSimIO(0x6F07,B0,0x00,0x00,0x09,"3F007FF06F07");
```

I am able to get back a successful response in uiccFileReadResponse, but after few seconds the system broadcasts `ACTION_UNSOL_RESPONSE_OEM_HOOK_RAW` intent and the device goes into Emergency Call Back mode.

The only way to exit out of this mode is a power cycle.

My device is rooted and I do have the `MODIFY_PHONE_STATE` permission.

It will be great if someone can guide me on this issue.

Comment: Hummm... reading the SIMCard IMSI :)

Comment: Yes... when the phone goes into emergency state, the only response I get back for APDU is 6F00... :(

Answer (score 1):

Well..

You can check RIL Logs (`adb logcat -b radio`) to check why phone is entering in Emergency Only Mode. Probably, is some error in CP side (Communication Processor).

If the error is in RIL side, you can debug... But if error is in CP side, it will be hard to fix without CP Logs(if fixable from App side). Without CP log, it is hard to tell what went wrong and also, each device uses a different chipset (Qualcomm, Marvell, Infineon, Broadcomm (RIP) etc)...

Try to test on different devices to check the result...

I'm not sure if it is possible.. But you can retrieve the imsi via [TelephonyManager..getSubscriberId()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getSubscriberId()):

```
TelephonyManager mTelephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String mIMSI = mTelephonyManager.getSubscriberId();
```